# LanguageType in a form

Tags: symfony

First of all, hello everyone and thanks for you attention. 
I'm doing an application with symfony. I'm using LanguageType to generate a field in my form with a big amount of languages, where the user must select one of them. The problem with LanguageType is that I'm only storing in my DB the language identifier. For example if I choose English, it will store in my DB "en", and I need to save the full name. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks for attention again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the ChoiceType Field in your FormType class and have it load all the languages you need. Check [here](http://symfony.com/doc/3.1/reference/forms/types/choice.html) to custom key/value pairs in your choices.

But in general I think it's a bad idea as you will store a translation of a language name. If you store the language code you can do whatever you want with it when retrieved

```
Intl::getLanguageBundle()->getLanguageName('en')
```

Comment: You were right. I make the translation before writing the date into the database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you can use the Intl bundle if so it is not a problem how they are stored. But you could always use this to convert the countrycodes from GB -> Great Britain

so what you do is get all countries store them in a variable then use the code below to convert it to a full name. Use this to convert codes to the full name and then tell the form to use these as a choice.

```
Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryName($variable);
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but the thing is I'm storing languages, not countries.
In my application I'm using LanguageType in a form to show a list of languages, but using LanguageType I'm storing in my db only the indentifier of the language and I need to store the whole language name.

Comment: wow sorry my bad misread it like @nilsM said  Intl::getLanguageBundle()->getLanguageName('en')